# Explaination for a code snippet related to classes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

There is a code snippet in the book "Hands on Machine Learning using Scikit-Learn, Keras and TensorFlow":

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
    
    # column index
    rooms_ix, bedrooms_ix, population_ix, households_ix = 3, 4, 5, 6
    
    class CombinedAttributesAdder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
        def __init__(self, add_bedrooms_per_room=True): # no *args or **kargs
            self.add_bedrooms_per_room = add_bedrooms_per_room
        def fit(self, X, y=None):
            return self  # nothing else to do
        def transform(self, X):
            rooms_per_household = X[:, rooms_ix] / X[:, households_ix]
            population_per_household = X[:, population_ix] / X[:, households_ix]
            if self.add_bedrooms_per_room:
                bedrooms_per_room = X[:, bedrooms_ix] / X[:, rooms_ix]
                return np.c_[X, rooms_per_household, population_per_household,
                             bedrooms_per_room]
            else:
                return np.c_[X, rooms_per_household, population_per_household]
    
    attr_adder = CombinedAttributesAdder(add_bedrooms_per_room=False)
    housing_extra_attribs = attr_adder.transform(housing.values)
```

The class is used to combine two attributes to create additional attributes. I did not understand the use of the second function (def fit)? Since it is not performing any actions, is it redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scikit-learn, an estimator is the class on which everything else is based. It is expected to implement the `.fit` method. Here's the [reference in the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html?highlight=baseestimator#different-objects).

In general the `.fit` method [operates on the training data and stores some resulting state on the object](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html?highlight=baseestimator#fitting).

In this particular case, the `.transform` method can operate on any data without any additional state learned from `.fit` so it doesn't need to actually do anything. You still need to define the `.fit` method though since `scikit-learn` expects all estimators to have one, even if it doesn't do anything.

Finally, this code is fragile because the column indices are defined outside of the object. I'd recommend [passing them to `__init__`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html?highlight=baseestimator#instantiation) so they are always tracked with the object. Then you can refer to them as `self.room_ix` and they are always kept with the object (e.g., if it is saved and reloaded).